# P/Invoke PostMessage crashes once the window received message

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I'm creating a window via P/Invoke Win32 API in a C# console application on .NET core. Following is the core code.

```
class WindowContext
{
    public IWindow MainLoop(Action guiMethod)// this is called somewhere else
    {
        MSG msg = new MSG();
        while (msg.message != 0x12/*WM_QUIT*/)
        {
            if (PeekMessage(ref msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0x0001/*PM_REMOVE*/))
            {
                TranslateMessage(ref msg);
                DispatchMessage(ref msg);
            }
        }
    }

    private IntPtr WindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        //....
    }

    public IWindow CreateWindow(Point position, Size size)// this is called to create a window
    {
        IntPtr hInstance = processHandle.DangerousGetHandle();
        string szAppName = "ImGuiApplication~";

        WNDCLASS wndclass;
        wndclass.style = 0x0002 /*CS_HREDRAW*/ | 0x0001/*CS_VREDRAW*/;
        wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;

        // RegisterClass(ref wndclass);

        // CreateWindowEx(...)
        // ...
    }
}
```

But the program keeps crashing once I move the mouse onto the window.

> The program '[18996] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -1073740771 (0xc000041d).

Finally I found out the crash occurred when the PeekMessage is called. But I couldn't tell why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching and debugging for 3 hours, finally I found the cause.

**The WinProc delegate instance is garbage collected.** Then the native code will access a invalid function pointer.

I mean this one `wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;`. The wndclass is a temporary object-a struct instance exactly-and will not exist on the stack when the program returns from `CreateWindow`. And after that, it is up to the CLR to determine whether to GC `wndclass.lpfnWndProc`.

So the solution is to make `wndclass` not a temporary object. For example,

```
class WindowContext
{
    WNDCLASS wndclass;
    public IWindow CreateWindow(Point position, Size size)// this is called to create a window
    {
        IntPtr hInstance = processHandle.DangerousGetHandle();
        string szAppName = "ImGuiApplication~";

        wndclass.style = 0x0002 /*CS_HREDRAW*/ | 0x0001/*CS_VREDRAW*/;
        wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    }
}
```

Now the wndclass lives the same long with the WindowContext instance. Problem solved.

Some similar problems on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5007211/3427520

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1616718/3427520